# Multiple if-else isn't working

Tags: javascript

```
var x = prompt("number between 50 and 100");

if (x.match(/hi/)) {
  alert("cool");
} else {
  alert("neni cool");
} else if (x==50 || x==100) {
  alert("skevele");
} else {
  alert("nic");
}
```

Can anyone explain why else if isn't working? Thanks for answers.

Comment: What are you adding to the prompt and what are you expecting?

Comment: Well if i type word to it it should alert cool/neni cool (it depends if it match "hi") and if i type number it should alert skvele or nic.

Comment: Please open your browser's developer console so that you can read the error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stack them like that. `}else{` statements are only ever the last cases in an if/then/else statement, because it only does it if the other cases haven't.

```
if(condition){
  what to do
}else if(condition 2){
  what to do if the first condition was not met
}else{
  if all else fails
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but this works and there is else if:



if(isNaN(x))
{if(x.match(/ahoj/)){alert("cool");} else {alert("neni cool");}}
  else if(x==50||x==100){alert("skvele");} else {alert("neni skvele");}

Answer (score 1):

You are putting an `else if` after an `else`. The `else if` will not be evaluated correctly, because `else` ends the `if` statement. If you want both statements to work, then try:

```
f (x.match(/hi/)) {
  alert("cool");
} else {
  alert("neni cool");
}

if (x==50 || x==100) {
  alert("skevele");
} else {
  alert("nic");
}
```

Comment: Thanks , tried it with using if(isNaN(x)) at the start and it worked even with else if .